# Mootools: Drag & Drop problems

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mootools

I've asked this question to the forums on the Mootools website and one person said that my class selection was corrupted before an admin came along and changed my post status to invalid.  Needless to say this did not help much.  I then posted to a google group for Mootools with no response.  My question is why doesn't the 'enter', 'leave', 'drop' events fire for my '.drop' elements?  The events for the .drag elements are working.

```
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SDI/includes/mootools-1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SDI/includes/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        var fx = [];
        $$('#draggables div').each(function(drag){
            new Drag.Move(drag, {
                droppables: $$('#droppables div'),
                onDrop: function(element, droppable){
                    if(!droppable) {
                    }
                    else {
                        element.setStyle('background-color', '#1d1d20');
                    }
                    element.dispose();
                },
                onEnter: function(element, droppable){
                    element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                },
                onLeave: function(element, droppable){
                    element.setStyle('background-color', '#000000');
                }
            });
        });

        $$('#droppables div').each(function(drop, index){
            drop.addEvents({
                'enter': function(el, obj){
                    drop.setStyle('background-color', '#78ba91');
                },
                'leave': function(el, obj){
                    drop.setStyle('background-color', '#1d1d20');
                },
                'drop': function(el, obj){
                    el.remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div id="draggables">
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
</div>

<div id="droppables">
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
</div>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it looks like there are a couple of issues here. As far as I can tell, there is no such thing as a "droppable" in mootools. This means your events like 'enter', 'leave' and 'drop' won't work. (These are events on the drag object)

If you change those names to events that elements in mootools have (as in, DOM events) your code works perfectly. For instance, if you change 'enter' and 'leave'  to  'mouseover' and 'mouseout', your events fire with no problem. (Opera 9.51 on Windows Vista)

This appears to be the revelant line in the documentation for this, which stats to use DOM events.

http://docs.mootools.net/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvents

Also, on that page, is a link to the events that regular elements can have

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_eventattributes.asp

However, [the advice "TG in SD" gave you in the nabble forums](http://mootools-users.660466.n2.nabble.com/Drag-and-drop-problem-I-m-having-td686391.html) is probably best. If you can, don't bother using these events. Put whatever it is you need to do in the draggable object, and save yourself all this hassle.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mootools Docs](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag.Move), "`droppables`" is one of the options expected by the `Drag.Move` class. In fact, this is the array of elements that interact with the element when it fires the "`drop`," "`enter`," and "`leave`" event.